Как найти в бд таблицу, которая одновременно содержит два столбца с разными известными нам наименованиями
Вот существует запрос, который позволяет найти в базе данных таблицу, которая содержит столбец с определенным наименованием:
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,  TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%А%'

А как составить запрос таким образом, чтобы мы могли найти таблицу, которая в себе содержит столбец с наименованием "А", а также столбец с наименованием "В".
То есть, например, есть таблица №1 со столбцами: А, В, С
А есть таблица №2 со столбцами: А, D, E
Нам надо составить запрос, чтобы отобрать только таблицу № 1

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

WHERE name IN GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT=2

Что вам мешает добавить к вашему запросу условие AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%'?

@SwaD а он в таком случае ищет, чтобы в одном наименовании столбца было и А, и В

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%А%' -- Условие для первого столбца
  OR  COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%' -- Условие для второго столбца
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Выбираем все таблицы, которые содержат хотя бы один из двух столбцов, для каждой считаем количество найденных строк, и оставляем те, для которых нашлось ровно 2.

К сожалению, оно не работает. Он все равно отбирает таблицы, где ИЛИ столбец с одним наименование, или с другим. Например, мне отобрал таблицы, где есть два столбца, содержащие в наименовании (условно) А, но не содержащие вообще столбца В.
Не могу догадаться, что надо исправить.

@user659233, тут два варианта. Либо вы при копировании потеряли последнюю строку, либо у вас условие составлено так, что под него попадают другие, не интересные вам столбцы. Попробуйте использовать сравнение на равенство (COLUMN_NAME  = 'A') вместо LIKE

по дроге ничего не потеряла. После доп проверки, поняла, что он отбирает так:

отберет, если в таблице есть либо столбец А, либо столбец В  (например, таблицу со столбцами А, АБ, С, Д - отберет, потому что А повторяется в двух столбцах, значит count =2)
⠀⠀⠀
отберет, если в таблице есть и столбец А, и столбец В (например, таблицу со столбцами А, В, С - отберет)
⠀⠀⠀
Если like заменить на = , то отбирает лучше.
Но все же это не то, что мне надо было, так как я не всегда знаю полное наименование столбца.
⠀⠀⠀
А как-то можно смешать  IN ('А', 'В') и LIKE ? не знаете?


Для MySql можно так:
SELECT t.table_name FROM information_schema.Tables t JOIN information_schema.Columns c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE t.table_schema = 'my_schema' AND c.column_name='A'
INTERSECT 
SELECT t.table_name FROM information_schema.Tables t JOIN information_schema.Columns c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE t.table_schema = 'my_schema' AND c.column_name='B'

без изысков, в лоб

Друзья, благодарю всех за ваши ответы, заинтересованность и участие.
У меня получилось добиться нужного результата с помощью вот такого запроса:
-- Таблицы с колонками, содержащими букву 'A'
WITH TablesWithA AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%А%'
),
-- Таблицы с колонками, содержащими букву 'B'
TablesWithB AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%В%'
)
-- INNER JOIN между двумя этими выборками
SELECT  a.TABLE_NAME AS TableWithA
b.TABLE_NAME AS TableWithB
FROM TablesWithA a
INNER JOIN TablesWithB b ON a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME; 

